# bash парсинг html

Tags: bash, grep, sed

Есть страничка лога сервера - такого типа:

```
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <titile></title>
   <body>
       <table>
           <tr></tr>
           <tr></tr>
           <tr></tr>
       </table>        
       #Много таких блоков
       <table>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
       </table>
```

Вполне нормально обходился такого рода консткурцией

```
cat index.html | grep "Нужное событие:" -A 4 -B 21
```

Которая искала нужное мне слово сочетание и показывало на 4 строки ниже - это было начало блока "table"  и соотвественно на 21 строку выше, где было начало блока table.

Все было хорошо, но  пошли не которые изменения, и количество строк tr-tr  стало меняться, то больше, то меньше.

И соотвестсенно, да и так бы хорошо сделать в самом начале, поставить поиск/вывод между блоками table-table

А вот как реализовать на bash не пойму... grep чтот не выдал мне подсказки, а sed'ом могу только заменить блок между строками, а вот вывести в упор не вижу как ...

Подскажите.
Спасибо.

Comment: А внутри <table> где то глубже других <table> надеюсь не бывает ? И я правильно понял, что нам нужен полный блок table внутри которого где то присутствует некий ключевой текст ?

Comment: Внутри table  других table нет) И да, нужен полностью блок между table/table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat index.html | sed -n '/<table>/{h;bo};H;/<\/table>/{g;/Нужное событие:/p};:o'
```

Расшифровка:

```
/<table>/{         # Когда видим <table>
          h;       # заменяем текущий "hold space" (очищаем предыдущий)
          bo};     # И уходим на метку "o"
H;                 # добавляем текущую строку в буфер "hold space"
/<\/table>/{       # Если таблица заканчивается (</table>)
           g;      # Извлекаем все из "hold space"
     /событие:/p}; # Если в накопленном буфере есть нужный текст печатаем его
:o                 # Метка для перехода "o", конец обработки строки
```

Comment: а в sed'е убрать чувствительность регистра можно же? в grep'e это -i,  а sed'e?

Comment: К выражению добавьте `I`, т.е. для поиска события и печати `/событие:/Ip`