# Замена текста в файлах linux

Tags: linux

Есть много разных файлов лежащих в разных папках , в которых встерчается одинаковый текст.В них нужно периодически заменять не одну строку, а целые куски кода на другой произвольный кусок и сразу массово во всех аналогичных файлах.

В Windows пользовался textreplacer, а на linux не могу найти альтренативу - если есть подскажите. Также желательно всетаки заменять именно в консоли -не везде графика есть.

Читал про sed с помощью которого заменяют сроку регулярными выражениями, а мне надо кусок текста, тоесть там будет еще и пробелы переносы строк и прочее.
Спасибо.

Comment: и что что там пробелы и переносы? `\s - пробельные символы` - вот решение для пробелов переносов итд

Comment: да и посмотрите вот тут https://toster.ru/q/10722

Comment: Для замены "кусков кода" пользуются IDE (с рефакторингами).

Comment: С одной стороны sed может менять не только по регуляркам. по хорошему он вообще полный по тьюрингу язык. Вот например печать блоков html, если в них есть текст https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/493481/194569  Так что при желании на нем можно сделать все что угодно. С другой стороны писать на нем все таки достаточно муторно и могу предложить посмотреть в сторону языка _perl_ сейчас он по умолчанию есть в большинстве сборок linux и изначально создавался как раз для решения подобных задач.

Comment: Ну это не дело составлять регулярки постоянно. Если в textreplacer просто вырезал и вставил что искать и на что заменить и такого по 5 раз надень. все это на удаленных серверах графики там нет. приходится править локально за 2 минуты и заливать долго и нудно через фтп по 50 минут руками то быстрее на 30 мину но кому оно надо руками. Вот и хотелось бы также удаленно . Попробую с перлом разобратся если там не тоже самое

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/573730/178576

Comment: `sed` это умеет, вопрос, надо ли так заморачиваться? Может быть написать программу так (если это код), чтобы не было дублирующихся кусков?

Answer (score 2):

в принципе, можно воспользоваться возможностями программы *patch*.

например, у вас есть два файла: `что-меняем` и `на-что-меняем`:

```
$ cat что-меняем
строка1
строка2
строка3
$ cat на-что-меняем
замена1
замена2
```

и есть файл, в котором надо произвести замену:

```
$ cat изменяемый-файл
строка-1
строка0
строка1
строка2
строка3
строка4
```

из двух исходных файлов надо сформировать «минимальный» патч. выглядеть он должен так:

```
@@ -0,3 +0,2 @@
-строка1
-строка2
-строка3
+замена1
+замена2
```

в первой строке цифра `3` — это количество заменяемых строк (т.е., длина файла `что-меняем`), а `2` — сколько строк получится в результате (т.е., длина файла `на-что-меняем`). а дальше идут строки обоих файлов — удаляемые предварены символом `-`, добавляемые — символом `+`.

удобнее эту процедуру производить скриптом примерно такого содержания:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "@@ -0,$(wc -l < $1) +0,$(wc -l < $2) @@"
sed 's/^/-/' $1
sed 's/^/+/' $2
```

ему надо передать аргументами два исходных файла и записать готовый патч в файл:

```
$ ./скрипт что-меняем на-что-меняем > патч
```

---

а теперь, собственно, вызов программы *patch*:

```
$ patch -f --no-backup-if-mismatch -r - изменяемый-файл патч
patching file изменяемый-файл
Hunk #1 succeeded at 5 (offset 5 lines).
```

результат:

```
$ cat изменяемый-файл
строка-1
строка0
замена1
замена2
строка4
```

---

использованные опции программы *patch*:

- `-f` («force») — не задавать лишних вопросов. удобно при пакетной обработке
- `--no-backup-if-mismatch` — не создавать бэкапы изменяемых файлов
- `-r -` — не создавать файл с reject-ами (несовпавшими фрагментами)

---

p.s. если вам надо менять несколько фрагментов текста, то все такие замены можно дописать в один патч (тем же вышеприведённым скриптом):

```
$ ./скрипт что-меняем2 на-что-меняем2 >> патч
$ ./скрипт что-меняем3 на-что-меняем3 >> патч
...
```